# GRUB не грузится

Tags: grub, ubuntu

Друзья, помогите решить проблему, не могу востановить GRUB пробовал разные варианты (http://ubuntologia.ru/grub2-recovery), перерыл кучу инфы, но ничего не помогает.

При загрузке вылезает:

```
GRUB>
```

и черный экран.

```
# fdisk -l

Device              Boot        Start    End      Blocks      Id  System
/dev/sda1           *           1        5737     46082421    7   HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2                       5738     17653    95715270    7   HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3                       17654    21891    34039809    5   Extended
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda4                       21891    30402    68360192    83  Linux
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda5                       17654    21360    29769728    83  Linux
/dev/sda6                       21360    21891    4269056     82  Linux swap /Solaris
```

Answer (score 1):

По выводу `fdisk -l` видно, что `sda4` в расширенной обрасти, его проще сконвертить в первичный раздел, даже скопировать всё из `sda5` в `sda4`, сделать его загрузочным и восстановить grub туда, а `sda5` сделать бэкапом.

Comment: Grub стоит на /dev/sdа5 там же корневой раздел

Comment: Я бы  загрузочный раздел (тут он же корневая система) не размещал в расширенном разделе. Я так понимаю, что он в sda4.. Можно ли его вынести из расширенного блока?Тогда всё будет проще, и, скорее всего, по вышеприведённому хауту сможет быть восстановлен.

Comment: Если это новая установка Линукс, лучше выделить под корень основной раздел и просто установить туда.А вообще gparted спасёт, если просто конвертировать раздел в основной

Comment: Извените но не нашел в GParted(Ubuntu 9.04 liveCD) конвертер для основного раздела.И вопрос есть /dev/sda3 это разширенный в котом находятся sda5 (корневой с grub) и sda6 swap,Так же есть /dev/sda4 оснавной раздел, на котором бэкап sda5как можно настроить grub на sda4(backup) который фактически настроен для sda5?извените если запустал, напишу подробней если нужно.